# Using htaccess to redirect query urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect a multiple urls within a few different categories using htaccess. The current structure is;

.com/category/subcat/product.html?querystring=123

And I need all versions of the querystring URL to redirect to;

.com/product.html

I don't mind writing a few lines for multiple categories but there are 1000's of variations of the querystring and cannot write all of them out.

Anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)querystring=123(&|$)
RewriteRule ^category/subcat/product\.html$ /product.html? [L,R=301]
```

As for the variations, if it's just a matter of a different numeric ID, then you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)jewelry_(metal|carat|colour|clarity)=[0-9]+(&|$)
```

If the "product" part is supposed to be variable, then replace the line with the rule with:

```
RewriteRule ^category/subcat/(.+)\.html$ /$1.html? [L,R=301]
```

If "category" and "subcat" can be anything then:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+)\.html$ /$1.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response the query string is not just the numerical value the whole string can change and I need to accommodate for that. I need to keep /product.html the same but want to use this htaccess for all products eg /product1.html and /product2.html etc.

Comment: @user2267784 are you saying the query string can be anything? And if there's a query string at all, redirect?

Comment: Yes so the current query string on a product is ?jewelry_metal=324&jewelry_carat=2&jewelry_colour=276&jewelry_clarity=261 but this can change order, numbers and not all queries show. So I need /products23.html?jewelry_metal=324&jewelry_carat=2&jewelry_colour=276&jewelry_clarity=261 and variations to redirect to /products23.html

Comment: @user2267784 all of this stuff would have been *immensely* useful from the start, as it's impossible to answer your question without this information. See the edit above

Comment: My apologies for not detailing this information before, thank you for the updated information